# C++ Struct in Header

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a simple struct here:

color.h:

```
#ifndef COLOR_H_
#define COLOR_H_
struct Color{
    float r,g,b;
};
#endif
```

tile.cpp

```
#include "color.h"
 void display(int x, int y, int tile_size, Color col){
   glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
   glColor3f(col.r,col.g,col.b);
   ...
}
```

But I get the following errors:

color.h: 3: color.h: struct: not found

color.h: 4: color.h: float: not found

color.h: 5: color.h: Syntax error: "}" unexpected

Comment: How do you compile this?

Comment: What lines of code do you have immediately before `#include "color.h"`?

Comment: I'm compiling by doing g++ -lGl -lglut main.cpp -o run
Before '#include "color.h"' I have 
'#include <GL/glut.h> #include "tile.h"' I actually changed my code slightly, in tile.cpp it's 'void tile::display' because display display is declared in tile.h. I see that's a problem now.

Comment: You have a problem in `tile.h`, Most likely you're missing a semicolon somewhere.